Subdivision and Face selection problems
I'm looking to accurately subdivide a face.
Please walk with me.

I have an object on my screen. In the edit mode, I'm looking subdivide that face.


I select the immediate top left vertex and the immediate top right vertex, subdivided it to create a vertex in the middle. I did the same to the immediate bottom left and right vertex 

I select the newly created vertices and tap on the F button to join both vertices; It created an edge. Now the face is divided. It looks like it's divided, but apparently it isn't. 

If I try to select a face either on the right or left, the whole face is selected. So it pretty much looks like the face wasn't divided at all. 


Here is what worked:

I selected the whole face, right-clicked, subdivided it, and then dissolved the horizontal edges. It looked neat. 

My question is: Why didn't it subdivide properly in the first attempt?
Thank you.

Use Ctrl-J to join the vertices, create the edge, and subdivide the Face. 'F' will just create a disconnected edge between them but not subdivide the face. You can demonstrate that by subdividing the edge created with 'F', selecting the centre vert, and moving it up with G Z.

@JohnEason Ctrl+J or J? With Ctrl+J you join objects in Object Mode.

@GordonBrinkmann Sorry, just 'J'. Had other things on my mind this week! I'm sure I did an answer here with an animated Gif explaining this a while ago but can't find it now.

 F  is for New Edge/Face from Vertices so it does that - it creates a new face or edge from vertices that can be separate from other geometry between those vertices, and it does not and is not supposed to divide faces.

Concect Vertex Path( J ) just below it in the Vertex menu( Ctrl  +  V ) does connect vertices with a path on surface dividing existing geometry:

However if you want to subdivide geometry, you can do just that with Subdivide operation alone. You just need to select the correct geometry to get your result - in this case that would be 2 edges of the face:


Thank you so much. This just helped.
